# Animate Scale Button Sprite C# Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am working on a VR-UI in Unity and i want to scale the Sprite of a Button on Gaze/Looking at it. Right now the code is looking like this.

```
private void HandleOver()
   {
       isOver = true;
       StartCoroutine(WaitAndClick());

       //m_Image.color = Color.cyan;

           m_Image.rectTransform.sizeDelta += new Vector2(10, 10);

   }

   private void HandleOut()
   {
       isOver = false;
       //m_Image.color = Color.white;

           m_Image.rectTransform.sizeDelta = m_Image.rectTransform.sizeDelta - new Vector2(10, 10);

   }
```

These are basically 2 voids for Entering and leaving the Object.
Right now it is working fine but i would like that it animates up. With this code it is an instant change of scale. Also Can i access only the sprite of m_Image so childobjects are not changed?

I would appreciate any Help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `Coroutine` to animate the button size like

```
IEnumerator MakeBig()
{
    var targetSize = m_Image.rectTransform.sizeDelta + new Vector2(10, 10);

    while (m_Image.rectTransform.sizeDelta != targetSize) {
        m_Image.rectTransform.sizeDelta += new Vector2(1, 1);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
    }
}
```

Then in `HandleOver` you start it like this

```
makeHuge = StartCoroutine (MakeBig());
```

We need to store a reference to the `Coroutine` somewhere, so we can try to stop the it in case `HandleOut` is triggered before `MakeBig` is finished.

So in `HandleOut` you would do something like

```
StopCoroutine(makeHuge);
```

and then vice versa for `HandleOver`